# How to connect to XP Home PC from XP Pro using Remote Desktop

Tags: windows-xp, remote-desktop

I want to connect to my XP Home PC on the same LAN workgroup (MSHOME) with my XP Pro machine - but I always get the following error

> Remote Desktop Disconnected
>   This computer can't connect to the remote
>   computer.
>
> Try connecting again. If the problem
>   continues, contact the owner of the
>   remote computer or your network
>   administrator.

How do I solve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Windows XP Home does NOT support inbound Remote Desktop. Use [VNC](http://www.realvnc.com/).

Comment: You used to be able to do a registry tweak to make Home think it was Pro, and then install remote desktop.  MS patched that out recently though :(

Comment: Not worth the effort and risk of finding your XP serial on Microsoft's black book. See my answer regarding Remote Assistance.

Answer (score 2):

use **[Teamviewer](http://teamviewer.com/index.aspx)**, by far best quality of any remote desktop software i have yet come accross. Teamviewer is free for personal use and can be configured to be used locally (LAN).

Comment: +1 This is your best bet. I have personally used Team Viewer on relative's computers to make software repairs & downloads.

Comment: Team viewer sounds very much like LogMeIn Hamachi2 (the non-managed version) in the method that it uses for connections.

Answer (score 2):

Windows XP Home supports Remote Assistance.
See this article for detailed instructions on its use : ["How to use remote assistance in Windows XP"](http://www.windowsnetworking.com/articles_tutorials/wxprmass.html).

Remote Assistance is similar to Remote Desktop, only available in Windows XP Professional, but while Remote Desktop allows to connect to a host-computer without any user action on the
host system, Remote Assistance requires a user to be present to accept an incoming connection.

Answer (score 1):

Use [LogMeIn](https://secure.logmein.com/US/products/free/). It's free and very simple to use.

Comment: This is an old answer, but sadly LogMeIn has done away with their free product.